# Relationship between lifetime of tech civilisations and time taken for a roundtrip between two such civilisations

Tags: mathematical-astronomy, celestial-mechanics

Here is a statement of the question, which is taken from Chaisson and McMillan's Astronomy: A Beginner's Guide to the Universe.

*Assume that the number of (technological) civilisations in the Milky Way Galaxy is equal to the average lifetime of a civilisation. Assuming that civilisations are uniformly spread over a two-dimensional galactic disk of radius 15 kiloparsecs, and all have the same lifetime, calculate the minimum lifetime for which a two-way radio communication with our nearest neighbour would be possible before our civilisation ends. Repeat the calculation for a round-trip personal visit, using a spacecraft that travels at 50 kilometres per second.*

Here is my approach to the problem:

Let $n$ be the number of   civilisations in the Milky Way and let $k$ be the average lifetime of a civilisation in years. By hypothesis, $n=k$. We will also assume that the galaxy is overlaid with a grid of squares, each of which has a single civilisation at its centre.

The area of the galactic disk is $15^2 \pi =225\pi $ kiloparsecs.  Since the civilisations are distributed uniformly, it follows that each civilisation is centred in a square whose area is $\frac{225\pi }{n} $ kiloparsecs. If $s$ is the length of a side of such a square in kiloparsecs, then $s$ is also the distance between the centres of two adjacent squares, hence, two civilisations. From the structure of the grid, $s$ represents the shortest distance between any pair of civilisations in the Milky Way. Note that $s^2= \frac{225\pi }{n} $ and hence $s=\frac{15\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{n} }$ kiloparsecs.

The minimum roundtrip distance between any pair of civilisations is therefore $2s=\frac{30\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{n}} $ kiloparsecs. If $v$ is the velocity  in kilometres per second taken for a roundtrip between two such civilisations, then the time, $t$ taken in seconds to make that roundtrip is given by  $$t=\frac{2s\cdot 3.09 \cdot 10^{16} }{v} = \frac{30\sqrt{\pi } \cdot 3.09 \cdot 10^{16} }{v\sqrt{n}}.$$

We require that $$t\leq 365\cdot 24\cdot 60^2 k .$$ Recalling that $k=n$, we compute:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}  \frac{30\sqrt{\pi } \cdot 3.09 \cdot 10^{16} }{v\sqrt{k}} & \leq 365\cdot 24\cdot 60^2 k \\
  \frac{30\sqrt{\pi } \cdot 3.09 \cdot 10^{16} }{365\cdot 24\cdot 60^2 v } & \leq  k^\frac{3}{2} \\
  \Big{(}\frac{30\sqrt{\pi } \cdot 3.09 \cdot 10^{16} }{365\cdot 24\cdot 60^2 v }\Big{)}^\frac{2}{3} & \leq  k .
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}

For radio communication, $v= c=3\cdot 10^5 $ kilometres per second. Inserting this into the  inequality, we see that correct to two significant figures $k\geq 3100 $  years.

For our spacecraft, $v=50$ kilometres per second. Inserting this into the   inequality, we see that $k\geq  1000000 $ years.

*I chose to use a square grid since my answer for radio communication agreed with Chaisson and McMillian's answer when I used that approach. I think one gets similar numbers when one overlays the galaxy with equilateral triangles or regular hexagons, but squares seemed the simplest. Using circles also gave a similar result, but it is of course harder to cover the whole galaxy that way. Unfortunately, Chaisson and McMillian gave an answer of 3000000 years for the spacecraft situation. Therefore, either my approach is seriously flawed, or there is a typo in the answers. Both are entirely possible. Can anyway spot a serious flaw in my approach?*

Comment: The first sentence in that beginners guide is already nonsense. Number and lifetime have different units. Voting to close.

Comment: Sure- but they can have the same value for specific units which is what is happening here. The argument that Chaisson/McMillan made to justify $n=k$ comes from the Drake equation where they took the rate of star formation to be 10 stars per year, the average number of habitable stars per planetary system to be 0.1, and the remaining factors to be 1. It's a bit arbitrary, but then again, so are most estimates for the factors of the Drake equation.

Comment: Correction: one of the factors in the Drake equation is the lifetime of a tech civilization. That was left unknown with the product of the remaining factors being 1.

Comment: Just a guess, I have not actually worked it out: in the computation of the roundtrip time you seem not to be taking into account relativity, namely, it seems to me you are computing the time that passes on board a ship that does a roundtrip, not the time that passes for an observer stationary at one of the civilization points...

Comment: 50 kilometres per second isn't particularly fast. I'm not sure relativity at that speed would make that much of a difference, but I will think about it.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the (constant) speed $v$ and the distance $s$ in question are both in a reference frame at rest with the galaxy, so the roundtrip time $t$ indeed is just twice the ratio of the two and is relative to that same reference frame. -- I cannot find anything wrong with your approach.